# How to update cordova.js?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I need to update cordova.js in order to have issue CB-7868 fixed on a Cordova project of mine.

I ran all commands stated in this [post](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/11/13/tools-release.html) but I can't get cordova.js updated.

My Cordova project is for the Android platform.

Comment: Did you update the platform as well? Rebuild it?

Comment: Yes. I performed a `sudo npm install -g cordova` according to the post. Then I ran `cordova platform update ios`. I also ran `cordova prepare android`. Lastly, I refreshed all files in Eclipse.

Comment: Don't you mean `cordova platform update android` ?

Comment: I mean, `cordova platform update android` :)

Comment: That should be enough then. If you aren't seeing the bug fixed I'd suggest posting on the Cordova issue itself and letting them know.

Comment: FYI, it looks like someone else isn't seeing it either. Link to issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7868

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually update NPM package with fix, or wait for next tools release (later then Nov 13)

- If you will wait for **next release** then you should run `cordova platform update android`
- If you want to **one-time patch** then you have to replace content of `platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js` with your patched version, or modify that file according to your needs.
- If you want to **permanently have manually patch** then you have to do following steps.

  a) Open cordova NPM package where it is stored by NPM.

  **On Windows**:
  %appdata%\npm-cache\cordova-js

  **On Linux**
  ~/.npm/cordova-js

  b) Inside that you will see specific version of Cordova, 3.7.1 for example.

  c) Inside that folder package.tgz, unpack it content to another folder, let's use `~/cordova-js-modified` for reference.

  d) Modify file `package/cordova.js` according to your needs and save.

  e) Repack content of `~/cordova-js-modified` to `package.tgz` and place it again in the `3.7.1` folder.

  f) Now you will have modified version which will be applied each time you run `cordova` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing as follows

- copy `platforms/android/assets/www/cordova.js` to `www/cordova.patched.js`;
- edit `www/cordova.patched.js` to replace `clobber` function with the updated one from `cordova-js@3.7.2`;
- edit `www/index.html` to link `cordova.patched.js` instead of `cordova.js`;
- run `cordova prepare android`.

I also put a `console.warn` to remember I'm using a patched version of `cordova.js`.